# Calling QQuickPaintedItem::update() in worker thread didn't redraw

Tags: c++, qt

Using Qt 5.15 with QML, C++.

Hi. I'm working on my custom QML type which inherits `QQuickPaintedItem` class.
In first implementation, the image to be drawn is generated in the `paint` method and it worked well. The following code is my first implementation in simple.

```cpp
class MyType : public QQuickPaintedItem {
public: 
  // Call this function when the image needs to be re-drawn
  void NeedToDraw() {
    QQuickPaintedItem::update();
  }
  
  void paint(QPainter* painter) override {
    __PrepareImage(&image_); 
    painter->drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), image_);
  }
  
private: 
  // Generate @image
  __PrepareImage(QImage* image); 

private: 
  QImage image_;
};
```

In this code, the main (GUI) thread is locked until the `PrepareImage()` is done. It is problem when calling `PrepareImage()` takes a long time.
So I made a worker thread for preparing the image(it's okay for images to update a little late). The following code is what I want to implement.

```cpp
class MyType : public QQuickPaintedItem {
public: 
  // Call this function when the image needs to be re-drawn
  void NeedToDraw() {
    if (thread_ != nullptr && thread_->isRunning()) return;
    thread_ = QThread::create(__PrepareImage, this, &image_);
    thread_->start();
  }

  void paint(QPainter* painter) override {
    painter->drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), image_);
  }
  
private: 
  // Generate @image and call @QQuickPaintedItem::update
  __PrepareImage(QImage* image) {

    // Generates image

    QQuickPaintedItem::update();
  }

private: 
  QThread thread_ = nullptr;
  QImage image_;
};
```

The only changed thing is calling `update()` inside the worker thread, but it didn't draw; the `thread_` worked, but the overrided `paint()` method never be called.
Couldn't find any mention of calling `update()` in a multithreaded in Qt documentation. How can I call the `update()` in a worker thread appropriately?

Comment: I have not enough experience with QML, but I doubt there would be any change: UI elements are not thread safe, and you cannot access them (including calling their functions/methods) from external threads. You're already using QThread, your missing step is using *signals*, which is the **only** proper way to notify the main thread that an UI element needs to do something in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QT you cannot usually use GUI elements created in the main thread (like your `MyType`) from another thread. Fortunately the fix is very easy, when your worker finishes the job, just `emit` the signal to tell the main thread that the image is ready for rendering:

```
  __PrepareImage(QImage* image) {

    // Generates image

    emit imageReady(image);
  }
```

Implement some slot `void onImageReady(QImage*)` (from your design I can also tell that `QImage*` arg might not be really needed) and connect it to `imageReady` signal. QT should automatically chose the [queued connection type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), so the slot will be already executed in the main thread.

You don't even need to use `QThread::create(__PrepareImage, this, &image_)` for that if you don't want, standard `std::async` will do the job as well.